# Javascript prevent re-loop through divs

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops

I have the following code

```
function loopCalendar() { // loop all calendar divs
    var labels = loopDivs('calendarDiv', 'btn_'), // loop calendar buttons
        arrows = loopDivs('calendarDiv', 'icon_'), // loop calendar arrows
        content = loopDivs('calendarDiv', 'content_'); // loop calendar content

    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var l = labels[i],
            a = arrows[i],
            c = content[i];

        (function(l, a, c) {
            // add event on click
            On(document.getElementById(l), ['click', 'touch'], function(e){
                // show content of the clicked div
                showContent(c, a);
                // loop calendar availabilities
                loopAvailabilities(c);
            });
        })(l, a, c);
    }
}
```

loopDivs() loops to a given div with a given id and brings back all the ids.

Basically this script loops through a calendar and gets the id of each month, the id of each arrow which represents a open/close icon for respective month and the id of the content of the month which contains bookings availabilities. Once it has finished the loop it shows the content of that month and starts to loop again through the days of that month (loopAvailabilities()). in loopAvailabilities() there's another similar script which this time adds an AJAX GET REQUEST on each day which will bring the clicked day availabilities.

Everything works fine but if I close the month and open it again the AJAX REQUEST which was applied to a day starts to make 2 GET calls, and if I repeat the process of closing the month and re-open it the AJAX REQUEST starts to make as many requests as many times I open the respective month.

How will I prevent the repeating calls of the ajax request?

If you need the rest of the script I'll add it but it's a bit long and it's basically the same plus the AJAX call

Comment: Remove the click and touch event before you attach. An additional event handler gets attached each time loopCalendar method is getting called.

Comment: @Surender on loopCalendar() or loopAvailabilities() ?

Comment: On(document.getElementById(l), ['click', 'touch'], function(e){ }) this line to be specific. You need to reverse the effect of this, by removing the previous handler attached or you need to ensure that this gets called only once for each element.

Comment: @Surender thank you so much, I ended up calling the event only once foreach element

Comment: @Surender would you like to answer the question, so it doesn't stay as unanswered? I'm sure many people encounter this problem sooner or later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the click and touch event before you attach. An additional event handler gets attached each time loopCalendar method is getting called.

**On(document.getElementById(l), ['click', 'touch'], function(e){ })** This is the line where the problem lies. You need to reverse the effect of this, by removing the previous handler attached or you need to ensure that this gets called only once for each element.